# Unique array algorithm with incrementing duplicates

Tags: arrays, algorithm, insert

Need assistance in designing an algorithm to handle this need. Starting input would be an array that is already known to contain unique integers. Not necessarily ordered or sequential, could be positive or negative. Need to push a new integer to the array and keep items unique by incrementing the conflicting items. The order that they appear in should be preserved though. For example:
Start with array `[1 5 3 4 6]` and insert `3`.
The sequence should be:

> [1 5 3 4 6 **3**] - push 3
>   [1 5 **4** 4 6 3] - increment 3 to 4
>   [1 5 4 **5** 6 3] - increment 4 to 5
>   [1 **6** 4 5 6 3] - increment 5 to 6
>   [1 6 4 5 **7** 3] - increment 6 to 7

The input will not be very long, so efficiency is not a major concern, but should be manageable.

Comment: Could you specify your use case? Unless this is a homework question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't create some other data structure to work in tandem with your unsorted main `list`, then your `append` will run in `O(n^2)`, since worst case it has to find and increment every element in the `list`. Since you said the `list` is not long and efficiency should not be a problem, I assume this is ok.

Since you didn't specify a language, I can give you some pseudo-code for the basic algorithm you can use.

```
def incrementHelper(list, e):
    if (list.contains(e)):
        incrementHelper(list, e+1)
        list.set(list.indexOf(e), e+1)

def appendAndIncrement(list, e)
    incrementHelper(list, e)
    return list.append(e)
```

Edit: You are correct, that other solution wouldn't work - my bad. This one uses a recursive solution and should avoid the problem you mentioned.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee order though. `list.indexOf(e)` will return the first element that it finds. In my example where 4 is incremented to 5 it selects the second 4 that is encountered.

Comment: I think that will work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it recursively travels until it reaches the largest sequential number and then updates in reverse.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Since it updates largest to smallest, it always avoids having more than one copy of any element at any given time. Then it just appends the element at the end, after the list has been updated.

Comment: Worked great. With the changes to your solution doesn't this change the efficiency to O(n)?

Comment: Actually nevermind, i think its still O(n^2) because of the `list.contains(e)` that happens every time.

Comment: Yep, that's right. There are `n` possible calls to `incrementHelper`, and each one of those can call `list.contains(e)`.